To “digitize” means to turn something into a digital format that was previously not digital. What to call changing one digital format into another?
In the context of 2000s and pre-2000s media, we often used the words "digitize" and "digitization" to refer to the act of converting media in an electronic analog format, such as a VHS tape, to one in an electronic digital format, usually a DVD or in cloud-based storage. I'm very particular about how I worded that because that is MW's definition and the well-established original definition of the word in technology.
These days, with analog formats being obsolete, virtually all formats are electronically digital in some form, but we still use "digitize" to (awkwardly) refer to transferring digital physical media, like DVDs, to cloud-based media. There are many examples of this word misuse online, from online forums to tech websites. My question is the following: does a better, concise verb already exist to describe the act of transferring physical media (analog or digital) to media readily accessible on a computer drive or in a server-based cloud?
Example of where this potential word would be best suited:

First, we’ll go over some ways to digitize any DVDs or CDs you want to save. Why digitize? Not all physical media is available on streaming services (or available on the ones you currently pay for). With a digital copy, you can access that content on all your devices without any clunky optical drives.
How to digitize and declutter your CDs and DVDs

Once again, the physical media in question is already in digital format, hence the need for an updated word.

Related: "Is there a verb for online-ness and offline-ness?"

In a society where we "dial a number" on phones that don't have dials and "ring people" where there is no bell, Your peeve seems to be an example of fossilisation.

Oh yes, it peeves me when people ask "Do you want to buy a game disc or the digital version (download)?". The disc is digital too!

We also refer to the version of an app that's not for mobile as the "desktop version". Even though historically the word "desktop" referred to computer towers, that are nowadays supplanted by laptops.

@NicolaSap, actually most desktops back in the day weren't towers if my memory serves me correctly. Please forgive my pedanticism.

transcode

Transcoding is the direct digital-to-digital conversion of one encoding to another, such as for video data files, audio files (e.g., MP3, WAV), or character encoding (e.g., UTF-8, ISO/IEC 8859).
Wikipedia


WAV to MP3 is not "direct digital-to-digital conversion". It is lossy compression, from which the original cannot be recovered. Unlike converting an image from BMP to PNG format, which is reversible.

reversibility is not relevant. Transcoding translates one encoding to another encoding. This is the correct answer.

Note that copying the bytes unmodified (or just decrypting) from a video DVD to your hard drive would not be transcoding, just ripping.  Same word is used for extracting the audio from an audio CD.  (Often you'd then encode it lossless (e.g. FLAC) or lossy (AAC or Opus, or obsolete MP3; audio CDs don't use any compression so it's just encoding not transcoding).  (And yes, good video-player software can play a DVD with menus etc. from a directory structure of .VOB files.  Transcoding with x264 for example can preserve most of the quality at lower bitrate, and give a single file.)

@PeterCordes: Correct, but that falls outside of the question, which specifies that the digital format changes.  One could define ripping as "preservation of the digital representation while changing the analog encoding underlying the digital storage".  Also not all encoding is compression.  WAVE needs an encoding, can be linear, can be mu-law, and swapping between them can be classified as transcoding / conversion, even though there's no compression involved.

+1 and excellent. I came here to make sure this word was one of the answers.

@BenVoigt: The example at the bottom of the question, of "digitizing" a (video) DVD, presumably onto a home-theater PC or media server, doesn't necessarily imply doing anything more than copying the files from the DVD as-is.  If you like the DVD menus, that's a good way to keep them. They're playable over a home network from a file server in that state.  And some media-server programs like Plex do I think support that way of copying a DVD.  (For an audio CD, you would of course encode, or transcode from PCM if you prefer, because there's no reason to keep the raw CD-DA data.)

Transcoding was my first instinct.  On second thought, however, it became clear that's too specific.  Transcoding means changing the digital format.  The example, is talking about moving digital data from one storage medium to another, which doesn't necessarily change the encoding format.  Thus format shifting best describes the subject of the cited article.  One might transcode as they format shift, but transcoding with format shifting and format shifting without transcoding are also possibilities.

@PeterCordes: I completely agree with your last comment, but copying files between different storage technologies is changing the encoding underlying the digital representation.  CDs and DVDs are optical with Huffman error correcting codes, the copy created on a PC is likely an SSD with Flash memory and its own redundant error correction, while a file server may well use "spinning rust" HDD with magnetic disks and yet a different error correcting scheme.

@BenVoigt: By that logic, copying a file from an SSD or thumb drive to an HDD is also transcoding, or between different models of SSD, or over the network when the data gets encoded onto the wire for ethernet, and with TCP/IP framing...  The file data is the thing we're thinking in terms of, not how its stored on raw media (except on optical media like CD audio where there isn't a filesystem.)  The difference being that SSD/HDD storage devices present themselves as a flat array of bytes (or sectors), users and programs don't have to manually deal with their ECC, that's in their firmware.

OP specifically asks for "does a better, concise verb already exist to describe the act of transferring physical media (analog or digital) to media readily accessible on a computer drive or in a server-based cloud?" whereas transcoding is defined as "direct digital-to-digital conversion".  Unless transcoding can also be used for an analog to digital conversion, and a definition is found to support that, this is Not The Answer.

@PeterCordes "By that logic, copying a file from an SSD or thumb drive to an HDD is also transcoding, or between different models of SSD" Or even loading from a hard drive to active memory.

@Kirt: Interesting point, I'd missed that detail of the question, that they wanted a term that could apply to analogue sources as well.  Apparently there is some usage of "rip" when the source format is vinyl record or VHS, including https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/vhs-ripping .  I like to use "ripping" more precisely, just for extracting the content unmodified, so to me, ripping doesn't include the transcoding or encoding you'd often want to do.  But the meaning is still clear, and apparently this broader usage is not rare.  jake has already posted a minimal answer for "rip".

Files can be converted from one type to another, or data can be exported/imported from one format to a file in another format. Those are the most commonly used terms for changing the file type.
When the format stays the same, you simply copy the files to a device or upload them to a network.

Export doesn't fit at all for the OP's example of going from CD or DVD to typical computer file formats.  Or even from say .avi to .webm.  Maybe for a case where the audio and video streams are just copied unchanged to a different container, like mkvmerge does, but I wouldn't say "I exported the DivX video from my old AVI file to h.264 in an MKV, using FFmpeg".  I also wouldn't say "I exported my AVI to MKV".  I guess maybe in the context of using a video editor program that had loaded the AVI file.  I guess maybe you could also say you "imported" a DVD if using a GUI video editor.

But again, import/export only seem to fit when talking about using a GUI program, not to describe just the conversion from one format to another (including transcoding video and/or audio if desired or necessary due to the new contain not supporting the old stream formats.)

@PeterCordes Yes, if you read the whole sentence, you'll see that I said you can export and import data to/from a file. Each of the terms I mentioned refers to a different situation.

Can you use it in a sentence in a way that you think fits?  In my first comment's example "the DivX video" is "the [video] data" in the AVI file, and I don't think "export" sounds right the way I used it in that sentence.

“convert” is okay, but the other terms are rather dubious.

+1 for stating copy

Never had to convert wave files to mp3s? Or MKVs into MP4s? I guess not if all you do is stream from the cloud and never actually own anything. "Guess [y'all gonna] have to buy The White Album again...."

The most general term for this kind of process, whether involving digital formats or not, would be “format shifting”.
There are pages of search-engine hits for that phrase and a Wikipedia article under that exact title, so it’s a quite established term.

"Format shifting is the conversion of media files into different file format" - the phrase exists because the Wiki page needed a title.

@Mazura It would need one regardless. Good thing they didn’t need to pull one out of thin air.

I don't think it's a general term. Format shifting is converting a CD to MP3 because I want to play it on my portable player. The "shifting" is an analogy from legalese of time shifting, recording a TV program on tape to watch it later. It was phrased this way during lawsuits to weasel out of saying "recording" or "copying".

@user71659 Well, it's converting a CD to MP3, among other things.

@user3840170 The point is it's converting to MP3 order to prevent having to buy a new copy, which is somewhat of a legal gray area, just like recording TV programs was too. That's the shifting weasel word.

Although more modern words may exist if you are looking for something people may understand I believe "ripping" the media would be a correct thing to say. Or another word that would sound a little less informal would be simply "transfer."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"ripping" is usually the term used for creating a CD or DVD from other source. It wouldn't be used for transfering a DVD to the cloud.

@Barmar It's often used in the context of creating CDs, but "ripping" really just means that the data is copied from the original format and stored somewhere else - you have "ripped" it from the original format. If you make a copy of a CD, you have ripped it, whether you store the result on a hard drive or the cloud. The process of creating another CD or DVD with the copied data is burning, not ripping (commonly conflated). I agree "ripping" calls to mind copying CDs more than to the cloud, but the term is technically correct as "ripping" just indicates making a copy in another medium.

@Barmar The other way around.

@NuclearHoagie You're right, I was thinking of "burning". When creating CDs was common, I often saw both terms.

Nope. Ripping changes nothing. If it did, then it failed.

@Mazura: That's how I'd define "rip", too, but apparently the term also gets used for VHS and vinyl (and the OP asked for a term that can apply to analogue or digital physical media).  Presumably by analogy to ripping digital optical media, and maybe only by people who don't care about or didn't think about the difference, but there are lots of google hits.

https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/vhs-ripping has a sloppy definition that compares it to "CD to MP3 ripping", where I'd agree with you @Mazura : transcoding/encoding is a separate step from ripping. But at least the meaning is unambiguous, of getting physical media into a computer file, even if that computer file is lossily compressed and/or the source media was analogue.  It also implies that the process didn't introduce unnecessary loss like by pointing a camera at a screen, or speakers + mic for audio instead of directly digitizing an electrical signal.

Other answers already gave you various terminologies for different scenarios, but here is a more precise guide on how to use them in various source and target formats / locations / media:
Conversion terms

to digitize is when the source is analog (vinyl record, cassette tape, VHS tape, photo paper, 35mm film roll, movie reel, etc.), and it doesn't matter what the target format is, as long as it is a digital format (i.e. the content is represented in 1's and 0's).  The target can be Audio CD, DAT tape, DVD disc, Blu-ray disc,  MP3 audio file, MP4 video file, picture file (JPG, PNG, etc.), etc.

to convert is a more general term.  When the source is analog the target can be analog / digital, or when the source is digital, the target can be digital / analog.  The term can be substituted for "transcode", "compress", and "export", but it should not be used when the source and target are in a different location.

to export a digital source is to "convert" BUT usually only a subset of the source is extracted.  If the entire content is converted from a file the term "transcode" is more common (see below).  "export" is most commonly used when the content is embedded within an application, or when the source file format is proprietary.  The converse is to "import".  Several scenarios where "export" is used:

you "export" a report out of a database, or you export an Excel spreadsheet into the CSV format that doesn't preserve all information in the original Excel.  "import" will add information into a larger data store.

you "export" the data in one application / system to another application / system.  For example, you "export" your QuickBooks data to NetSuite, you "export" your smartphone data into computer files that you can then "import" into another smartphone, etc.

you "export" a picture / data from the original application that has a lot more complete information, such as exporting from Photoshop / paint.net that have multi-layer picture data, or from Visio that has the complete diagram definition, or from Microsoft Word that has the complete document information.  The application is the one doing the format conversion, usually from a proprietary format to a standard format (such as JPG, PNG, PDF, etc.) that doesn't require the application to be installed.



to transcode is to change the format of a digital source in its entirety (unlike an export which can be a subset).  Transcoding can be lossless (no change in resolution) or not, but usually implies lossless (at least perceptibly) even when the underlying transformation is lossy (i.e. not reversible).  If you know it's going to lose resolution, you use the term "compress" instead (see below).  The term is usually applied only to files, but not to physical media like a CD / DVD disc where you would use "rip" instead (see below).
"transcode" is also commonly used for character encoding conversion and for data file format conversion as well, not just for picture / audio / video files.

to rip a digital source is to extract the 1's and 0's of a physical media, usually an Audio CD, Video-CD, LaserDisc, DVD, or Blu-ray disc, into a set  of digital target files that have identical content (so lossless is implied), such as WAV files for Audio CD or VOB, IFO, BUP files from the internal file system of a DVD disc.  In this way, playing the target will result in an identical experience as playing the source.
But for WAV files, you usually do "compression" into MP3 files (or other audio formats) as the next step.  And for VOB files, you usually do "transcoding" plus optional "compression" on the audio, video, and subtitle streams separately, after which you would "multiplex" (package) the resulting processed streams into a standard container file format such as MP4 (MPEG-4).

to compress is to make the target smaller in size usually by reducing the resolution or by using a more efficient compression algorithm, which although inherently lossy, can be perceptibly lossless, thus introducing a measure of subjectivity depending on how the target is used.  For example,

it is very common to "compress" a picture from the high resolution raw format produced by a digital camera into a much lower resolution intended for a website.
Similarly, it is very common to "compress" the original studio recording audio file into a more space-efficient consumer format, such as the stereo 44.1 kHz WAV format used in Audio CDs, or to an even more efficient (but lossy) MPEG-1 Audio Layer III (MP3) format.

You can see "compress" as a more specific "transcode" operation but irreversible.  Another unrelated meaning of "compress" is to combine multiple files into a container file format (such as ZIP) which results in a smaller size, but which is always lossless and reversible.  "decompress" is the opposite operation.

to encrypt a digital file is to modify the file in such a way that additional information is needed to read it.  It's always lossless.  "decrypt" is the operation to apply the additional information (such as encryption key or password) to the encrypted file so it can be read normally.


Non-Conversion terms

to copy a digital source does NOT involve changing the format at all, so the target format and the content are usually identical.  You copy one Audio CD to another Audio CD, or you copy one MP3 file to another MP3 file, possibly with a different file name.  The location can be in the same computer ("local copy"), can be between one computer to another ("network copy"), or can be between a computer and a cloud (see "upload" / "download" below).

to upload is to "copy" between a non-cloud location to a cloud location, thus the format doesn't change either.  The converse is to "download".


Hope this helps.

I agree with your definition of ripping, but that makes your example of MP3 incongruous.  MP3 is always lossy.  Common lossless audio formats include WAV (uncompressed) and FLAC.  MP4 is a container that supports many codes, and you could for example put lossless h.264 in it.  Or when copying from a video-DVD or BluRay, the original video and audio streams are often ones that MP4 can handle, so ripping is just remuxing into MP4 without transcoding.  (for future readers, mux = multiplex = putting multiple streams e.g. audio + video into one file, usually with seek information.)

@PeterCordes Thanks for the feedback.  I knew I wasn't very precise since the target audience may not be technically savvy. But I did apply your feedback to make the definitions more correct, while still minimizing lingo. I believe we tech people have the educational responsibility to explain technical terms to lay audience well so they can understand technology better with little effort, which is the point of my answer.  Hopefully everything is okay now.

Yeah, good goal.  h.264 (aka AVC) is primarily a lossy format; many decoders don't even support the lossless profile (Hi444PP); FFmpeg does.  Ripping to it is only lossless when you're copying the already-lossy h.264 stream from a BluRay. (And you wouldn't have an h.264 file, you'd have it in a container like MP4)  Like MP3 for audio, it was the best available quality/bitrate tradeoff at the moment technology advanced far enough to make video on the Internet popular, so it's the baseline standard pretty much everything supports.

The key point is that uncompressed digital video is ridiculously huge (and lossless compression of it can't get much below half for most content), so physical media holding digital video wasn't a thing until lossy compression formats existed.  Unlike with audio where an hour of raw 16-bit / 44kHz audio will simply fit on a ~800 MB optical CD.  (Data CDs use some of that 800MB on an extra level of error-correction coding).  For video, it wasn't until MPEG1/2 (like in .mpg files) that we had VCD (video CD) and DVD.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaserDisc#Design used analog video, interesting!

The multiplexing operation usually adds "seek" (timestamp) information to the MP4 file so it can be safely streamed over a channel where some transmission loss is tolerated. - That's not what seek metadata does.  It's stored at one end of the file, as an index to where in the file to seek if the user wants to jump forward / backward.  Or for where to start streaming from if a client resumes at say 1 hour into a video.

When sending video over a channel that (unlike Internet TCP/IP like youtube) can't ask for a retransmit on loss, e.g. digital cable or broadcast TV, the framing is sufficiently self-synchronizing that a receiver can find place to restart decoding after a few seconds.  For video, typically at a keyframe.  I don't think a literal .mp4 file is suitable for this; actual broadcast would send different metadata with the audio/video.  Internet video streaming like youtube just uses TCP/IP to get a reliable stream, at the cost of latency.  (Unlike a 2-way video conference where latency matters.)

@PeterCordes Thank you again for your feedback.  I have purified the "rip" explanation further to be more technically correct.  Yes, the original stream source in DVD/Blu-Ray is already compressed, so "lossless" here implies faithful bitwise copy.  I have removed the "seek" comment as it's too technical for the scope of this answer.  It's surprisingly hard to find a detailed standard format of mp4 to see exactly where the "seek" byte structures are located and formatted (for hints to the media player), also for a common version that is broadcast over TCP/IP containing keyframes.

Yeah, good, seek metadata Just Works, no need to mention it.  MP4 is a very complicated container format, with lots of stuff for use-cases like web streaming as well as local file.  Keyframes are a thing for the video stream itself.  Those are the points where you can seek to without having to decode any previous frames to start playing, so a muxer would record their positions to make a seek index (whatever MP4 calls it). (Precise seeks decode+discard from the previous keyframe).  A truncated .avi or .mkv can be playable, and seekable without the index; the player just scans the streams itself


"Digitization" is also used to describe the process of populating
databases with files or data. While this usage is technically
inaccurate, it originates for the previously-proper use of the term
to describe the part of the process which involved converting the analog
sources (printed pictures, printed brochures, etc.) into the digital representation before uploading to the target database(s).
Dinesh Kumar Kaushik; Current Trends in Library and Information Science (2021)


Convert would be the general term for changing one digital format into another, regardless of the specific procedure used to achieve it.

You can also simply use the word "encode".
Google definition:

encode /ɪnˈkəʊd,ɛnˈkəʊd/ verb
[Computing] convert (information or an instruction) into a
particular form.
"the amount of time required to encode a wav file to
mp3 format"


Cloudify - wiktionary:

(computing) To convert and/or migrate data and application programs in order to make use of cloud computing.

There's also a noun, cloudification.

Did you mean to capitalize the C? Cloudify is the name of an open-source product that comes up in Google Books. Can you provide any examples of cloudify (small c) with your meaning? (I haven't found one yet.)

Stop talking about things you don't know. Why are you keeping giving false answers?

Usually when you are going from one digital format to another you are
Compressing or decompressing
Or, you are
Encrypting or decrypting
If you are not doing any of these you are wasting time but I doubt that words that mean that is what you are after...

At first, I didn’t understand the question until I saw the link you provided.
You’re probably annoyed by the title, right? Honestly, I didn’t think much of it at first, but after reading your analysis, I agree—it’s irritating. Let’s come up with a better title together:
How to digi-to-digi and declutter your CDs and DVDs
How to d2d (inspired by k8s) and declutter your CDs and DVDs
How to d3 (digi-to-digi and declutter) your CDs and DVDs
How to d6 (digi-to-digi and declutter your CDs and DVDs) (a lot of Ds, I know!)
The point is, there isn’t currently a term that perfectly fits our needs, so we have to create one ourselves, regardless of what others might think. Since you’re the first person to raise this question, you have the responsibility to come up with this new term, and I’ll just chime in for fun.
We also need to acknowledge that the misuse of words isn’t a new problem, and society tends to lag in addressing it. Plus, I’ve rarely heard of a situation where a term must be replaced—there are usually plenty of alternatives, like ignoring it, not caring about it, or simply using a different term.
I hope you become famous, so people will start adopting whatever word you decide on!
Here’s the initial answer I gave—I didn’t really understand the question at the time, and maybe I’m still making things up now because this is my first time participating in an English-speaking community. Haha!


Welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour]. Answers should simply be answers, with justification/corroboration. We don't need conversational comment. Also your answer should be in the typed text, not buried in an screenshot. The screenshot has a lot in common with generative AI. Please note we do not allow AI answers here and haven't for a couple of years.
